# Should I list class methods in the class docstring?

Tags: python, docstring

I am a bit confused by the PEP257 standard for documenting classes.

It says, "The docstring for a class should summarize its behavior and list the public methods and instance variables"

But it also says that all functions should have dosctrings (which, of course, I want, so that help() works).

But this seems to involve duplication i.e.

```
class foo:
    """A class

    Attributes
    ----------
    bar : str 
        A string

    Methods
    -------
    __init__(fish):
        Constructor, fish is a str which self.bar will be set to.
    baz():
        A function which does blah

    """

    def __init__(self, fish):
    """
    Constructs an XRTProductRequest object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fish : str
        A string, which the self.bar attribute will be set to.
    """
    etc...
```

This then is rather error prone because it means that when I realise that `__init__` also needs to recieve an int, then I have to remember to update the docs in 2 places, which I can guarantee I will forget.

It also makes the pydoc output duplicated: it prints my class docstring, but then says, "Methods defined here" and goes on to list all of the methods, via their own docstrings.

So, is this duplication really part of PEP257, or am I mis-reading it? Should I drop the "Methods"section of the class docstring, since each method has its own docstring? Or is this duplication really part of the standard?

TIA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes just drop the methods section from the class docstring. <strike>I've never ever seen something like that used.</strike><sup>(It *is* used in few places in the [standard library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/baf10da75072d1f8ec714d3c2c8550d34db343a9/Lib/datetime.py#L778-L785).)</sup>  The class docstring needs to just describe the class and the docstring of individual methods then handle describing themselves.

Also the wording in the PEP to me means that the class docstring "should" **list** the public methods, but not describe them in any other way.<sup>(This is also how the above standard library example does it.)</sup>  But as said, I would never even do that, since the code speaks for itself and that kind of listing is bound to get out-of-date.

Final note: I personally prefer to use the [Google docstring style](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html), because to me it's the clearest and cleanest.

Comment: Thanks. Although I note the other answer below says that I *should* duplicate, so it's nicely confusing. :) I prefer this answer simply because if complies with what makes sense to me....

Comment: The answer below, though answers the question "Should I list class methods in the class docstring".

Answer (score 2):

example:

```
class Animal:
    """
    A class used to represent an Animal

    ...

Attributes
----------
says_str : str
    a formatted string to print out what the animal says
name : str
    the name of the animal
sound : str
    the sound that the animal makes
num_legs : int
    the number of legs the animal has (default 4)

Methods
-------
says(sound=None)
    Prints the animals name and what sound it makes
"""

says_str = "A {name} says {sound}"

def __init__(self, name, sound, num_legs=4):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    name : str
        The name of the animal
    sound : str
        The sound the animal makes
    num_legs : int, optional
        The number of legs the animal (default is 4)
    """

    self.name = name
    self.sound = sound
    self.num_legs = num_legs

def says(self, sound=None):
    """Prints what the animals name is and what sound it makes.

    If the argument `sound` isn't passed in, the default Animal
    sound is used.

    Parameters
    ----------
    sound : str, optional
        The sound the animal makes (default is None)

    Raises
    ------
    NotImplementedError
        If no sound is set for the animal or passed in as a
        parameter.
    """

    if self.sound is None and sound is None:
        raise NotImplementedError("Silent Animals are not supported!")

    out_sound = self.sound if sound is None else sound
    print(self.says_str.format(name=self.name, sound=out_sound))
```

Yep, listing methods in the class docstring, then each method again documented, according to this standard.
I reccomend using sphinx, though: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/contents.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I follow the Sphinx thing though: Sphinx is a way of creating an HTML set of documentation built from the docstring, not the conventions for docstring, no?

Comment: There are different conventions, sphinx offers additionally generating documentation in multiple formats, but is not mandatory.